# passing dictionary values between functions

Tags: python, pandas, function, dictionary

Python 3.8 , windows 10

Hi All, im pretty new to Python so please be nice :)

I am having problems on the final stage of a piece of code writing that interacts with a busAPI. (no I am not a bus spotter)

So far I have taken in data from a user

Validated the service is one we support

Retrieved pertinent data about the service

Retrieved route information for the service, and passed this to the final part where I'm meant to map it.

Unfortunately, it is only plotting one point, the end stop

I can see my functions interacting as I have copious amounts of debug logging going on so I can see data flowing between functions etc.

```
    ....
    ....
    1
    DEBUG 4: Alyssum Walk , 51.89186 , 0.93168
    DEBUG 5: Alyssum Walk , 51.89186 , 0.93168
    DEBUG 5.1: map_it_dict{'stop': 'Alyssum Walk', 'latitude': 51.89186, 'longitude': 0.93168}
               stop  latitude  longitude
    0  Alyssum Walk  51.89186    0.93168
    1
    DEBUG 4: Azalea Court , 51.89278 , 0.93334
    DEBUG 5: Azalea Court , 51.89278 , 0.93334
    DEBUG 5.1: map_it_dict{'stop': 'Azalea Court', 'latitude': 51.89278, 'longitude': 0.93334}
               stop  latitude  longitude
    0  Azalea Court  51.89278    0.93334
    1
    DEBUG 4: Library , 51.89165 , 0.93706
    DEBUG 5: Library , 51.89165 , 0.93706
    DEBUG 5.1: map_it_dict{'stop': 'Library', 'latitude': 51.89165, 'longitude': 0.93706}
          stop  latitude  longitude
    0  Library  51.89165    0.93706
    1
    DEBUG 0: Returned from  bus_route(). Last Stop is Library , 51.89165 , 0.93706
```

As can be seen above I am getting consistent data across all my functions and my Pandas dataframe.

DEBUG 0 is the main funcntion

DEBUG 4 -comes from my function busroute. This queries a URL and returns the bust stops on the route. This is delivered with the bus stand name, and the lat and long of the bus stop. The final part of the busroute function passes the busstop, lat and long to the Map_it function

DEBUG 5 - is showing us that it is receiving the same data from the Bus_route function. finally , on line 19 you can see the pandas dataframe, again with the same information.

the ) is the index in my pandas data fram
the 1 is the number of items in the dictionary at that time ( total route is 53 items)

The data that comes in to my map_it function should plot the52 bus stops across a folium map. but it is only mapping the last one.

[image: Folium map showing only one marker, should be 53]

I think this is happening as the data that is passed over to the map_it function is being passed line by line and I suspect the dictionary is over written each time. hence the index of 0 against the datagram.

I get all the data in my bus_route function'

```
    What bus do you want?: 64
    The number 64 is a bus service we support
    DEBUG 0: From validate_bus() we got 64
    DEBUG 0: From bus_service(): Bus Number 64 , Traveling from: Greenstead, Essex, Traveling to: Shrub End, Essex
    DEBUG 4: Hazell Avenue , 51.87154 , 0.86659
    DEBUG 4: Paxman Avenue , 51.87186 , 0.86827
    DEBUG 4: Alderman Blaxhill School , 51.87236 , 0.87038
    ...
    ...
    ...
    DEBUG 4: Alyssum Walk , 51.89186 , 0.93168
    DEBUG 4: Azalea Court , 51.89278 , 0.93334
    DEBUG 4: Library , 51.89165 , 0.93706
    DEBUG 0: Returned from  bus_route(). Last Stop is Library , 51.89165 , 0.93706
```

Here is my code for the two functions.

```
    def bus_route(bus_number):
        # This function queries the transport API for route data for a specific bus service number
        # It receives input as bus_number from main()
        # it provides bus_stand, lat and long of each of the stops along the specific buses route
        # and passes them to map_it() for route mapping.

        bus = bus_number
        # Retrieve a URL via urllib3
        # This could be tidied up using data from URL but for expediancy it is coded in here
        # Use %s to pass in the Constants and Variables to make up the URL
        if bus == "64":
            url = BASE_URL + '/route/FESX/%s/inbound/1500IM2349B/2020-05-22/06:40/timetable.json?app_id=%s&app_key=%s' \
                             '&edge_geometry=false&stops=ALL' % (bus, APP_ID, API_KEY)
        elif bus == "65":
            url = BASE_URL + '/route/FESX/%s/inbound/1500IM2456B/2020-05-22/19:27/timetable.json?app_id=%s&app_key=%s' \
                             '&edge_geometry=false&stops=ALL' % (bus, APP_ID, API_KEY)
        elif bus == "67":
            url = BASE_URL + '/route/FESX/%s/inbound/150033038003/2020-05-22/06:55/timetable.json?app_id=%s&app_key=%s' \
                             '&edge_geometry=false&stops=ALL' % (bus, APP_ID, API_KEY)
        elif bus == "70":
            url = BASE_URL + '/route/FESX/%s/inbound/1500IM77A/2020-05-22/06:51/timetable.json?app_id=%s&app_key=%s' \
                             '&edge_geometry=false&stops=ALL' % (bus, APP_ID, API_KEY)
        elif bus == "74B":
            url = BASE_URL + '/route/FESX/%s/inbound/15003303800B/2020-05-22/20:10/timetable.json?app_id=%s&app_key=%s' \
                             '&edge_geometry=false&stops=ALL' % (bus, APP_ID, API_KEY)
        elif bus == "88":
            url = BASE_URL + '/route/FESX/%s/inbound/1500IM77A/2020-05-22/05:50/timetable.json?app_id=%s&app_key=%s' \
                             '&edge_geometry=false&stops=ALL' % (bus, APP_ID, API_KEY)
        else:
            url = BASE_URL + '/route/FESX/%s/inbound/1500IM52/2020-05-22/06:00/timetable.json?app_id=%s&app_key=%s' \
                             '&edge_geometry=false&stops=ALL' % (bus, APP_ID, API_KEY)

        http = urllib3.PoolManager()

        # Request our data, and decode the json data returned
        response = http.request('GET', url)
        bus_route_dict = json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8'))
        x = 0
        # iterate through our dictionary giving us the bus stop names and their
        # lat and long so we can plot them on a map.
        #while x < len(bus_route_dict['stops']):
        #    print(x)
        for stop in bus_route_dict['stops']:
            bus_stand = stop['stop_name']
            lat = stop['latitude']
            long = stop['longitude']
            print("DEBUG 4: " + bus_stand + " , " + str(lat) + " , " + str(long))
            #map_it(bus_stand, lat, long)
        return bus_stand, lat, long

    def map_it(bus_stand, lat, long):
        # This function maps teh bus route on a folium map
        # It receives input as bus_stand, lat, and long from bus_route

        # Folium mapping
        stop = bus_stand
        latitude = lat
        longitude = long

        # DEBUG code to show we are receiving code from get_route()
        print("DEBUG 5: " + stop + " , " + str(latitude) + " , " + str(longitude))

        # Setup a dictionary to store the information we need to build
        # a folium map
        map_it_dict = {}
        map_it_dict['stop'] = stop
        map_it_dict['latitude'] = latitude
        map_it_dict['longitude'] = longitude
        print("DEBUG 5.1: map_it_dict" + str(map_it_dict))

        # lets get the dict into pandas
        map_it_df = pd.DataFrame([map_it_dict])
        # Check we got data - we get it. tw 22/05/2020
        #print(map_it_df.head())

        # Prep data for the map
        locations = map_it_df[['latitude', 'longitude']]
        locationlist = locations.values.tolist()
        print(len(locationlist))

        # Now build the map
        # the Location is the Lat/Long for Colchester
        route_64 = folium.Map(location=[51.8959,0.8919] , zoom_start=14)
        for point in range(0, len(locationlist)):
            folium.Marker((locationlist[point]) , popup=map_it_dict['stop']).add_to(route_64)
            route_64.save("route_maps/route_64.html ")
```

I cant see where to  create my dictionary as all i seem to get out in the bus_route() function is single lines. I realise if i could get the print statement to append to the dictionary then that would be my problem solved.

Comment: create a list in `bus_route()` function and append result of `map_it()` function. And you have to return the `map_it_dict` dictionary from `map_it()` function.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly